# How to get the email address of google plus circles in android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I can get the email address of the google plus signed in user

```
  String emailuser = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
```

I can also get the google plus circles details using

```
Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient,null).setResultCallback(this);
```

But how to retrieve the google plus circles email addresses in android?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
public void onPeopleLoaded(ConnectionResult status, final PersonBuffer personBuffer,String nextPageToken) {

        if (status.getErrorCode() == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) 
        {           
            try
            {
                //Add all friends ids in an arraylist
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                //Loop through all the ids of google plus friends
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) 
                {
                    //mListItems.add(personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                    //mListIds.add(personBuffer.get(i).getId());  

                    friends_gplus_Ids += personBuffer.get(i).getId() + ",";
                    //Log.d("Emails", personBuffer.get(i).getOrganizations().toString());
                    //personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().size();

                    if((personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().size() > 0)) 
                    {
                        Log.d("Emails", personBuffer.get(i).getEmails().get(0).toString());
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.d("Emails", "Null");
                    }                                   
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                personBuffer.close(); 
            }
}
```